# how to create Master Page in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to create master page in mvvm. I created a `viewbox` that it's name is container for showing my `usercontrol`s and I have two classes, `RelayCommand` and `ViewModel`.

Here is my code:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();

    UserControls.History objHistory = new UserControls.History();
    UserControls.NewItem objNewItem = new UserControls.NewItem();
    UserControls.SideEffect objSideEffect = new UserControls.SideEffect();

    public ViewModel()
    {         
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(Open);

    }


    private ICommand openCommand;
    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get { return openCommand; }
        set { openCommand = value; }
    }

    public void Open(object sender)
    {

        if (sender.ToString() == "btnHistory")
        {
            objMainWindow.Container.Child = objHistory;

        }

        if (sender.ToString() == "btnNewItem")
        {

        }

        if (sender.ToString() == "btnSideEffect")
        {

        }

    }

}
```

And this is my `RelayCommand`:

```
public class RelayCommand:ICommand
{

   public RelayCommand(Action<object> _action)
   {
       actionCommand = _action;
   }

    private Action<object> actionCommand;




    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    } 


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter !=null)
        {
            actionCommand(parameter);
        }

        else
        {
            actionCommand("Null");
        }
    }

}
```

but when I run solution I faced with `NullRefrenceException` when it wanted to show my child of container.
I don't  know how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainWindow` instantiates when your program starts. So you shouldn't instantiate it again in your `ViewModel` (i.e. this line: `MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();`). You should use `DataBinding` instead.

Here is a sample code that gives you an idea:

First define a property of type `FrameworkElement` in you `ViewModel` and set it's value to your desired `UserControl` in the `Open` method.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FrameworkElement _myUc;
    public FrameworkElement MyUserControl
    {
        get
        {
            return _myUc;
        }
        set
        {
            _myUc= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyUserControl");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenCommand = new RelayCommand(Open);
    }

    public void Open(object sender)
    {
        if (sender.ToString() == "btnHistory")
        {
           MyUserControl = objHistory;
        }
    }

    // rest of your view model ...
}
```

Then instantiate your `ViewModel` as the `DataContext` of your `MainWindow` in the `Constructor`.

**MainWindow:**

```
public ViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyViewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = MyViewModel;
}
```

And Finally use a `ContentControl` (instead of `ViewBox`) [*see my note*] and bind it's `Content` to the `MyUserControl` property of your `ViewModel`.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding MyUserControl}"  x:Name="Container"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="btnHistory" Content="ShowHistory" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

This way each time `MyUserControl` changes, the `ContentControl` shows your desired `UserControl`.

*Note* that `Child` property of `ViewBox` is not a `DependencyProperty` and thus not bind-able.